# Python influx query inserting dates into query

Tags: python, influxdb

When I run the following statement to query influx I get the error :

> InfluxDBClientError: invalid timestamp string

```
date_from  = '2019-12-02 T00:00:00Z'
date_to = '2019-12-02T01:00:00Z'
"""SELECT "value" FROM "location/PRESSURE_SENSOR_1" WHERE time >= """ + '\'' + date_from + '\'' + """ and time <= '2019-12-02T01:00:00Z' """
```

If I run the following it works fine :

```
client.query("""SELECT "value" FROM "location/PRESSURE_SENSOR_1" where time >= '2019-10-02 00:00:00' and time < '2019-10-03 00:00:00'"""))
```

The aim is to build the statement where i can insert variables but i dont seam to be able to do it.  Any help appreciated? 
Thanks

Comment: Just for giggles and science, try putting the single-quotes inside the triple-quotes and get rid of the back-slash ones, e.g. `WHERE time >='""" + date_from  + """'`

Comment: Also: just in case someone ever uses your code in a bigger and less controlled environment, consider some sort of data-sanitizing before you concatenate strings. Otherwise, we're teaching the children out there some insecure habits. :)   https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2):

You should utilize bind_params in the api to accomplish this task.

```py
query = "SELECT value FROM 'location/PRESSURE_SENSOR_1' where time >= $start_time and time < $end_time"
bind_params = {'end_time': '2019-10-03 00:00:00', 'start_time': '2019-10-02 00:00:00'}
client.query(query, bind_params=bind_params))
```

Find more information here:
[Influx Client Documenation](https://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-documentation.html#influxdbclient)

Comment: When i run this i get "TypeError: query() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bind_params'".  Any ideas why client.query doesnt like the parameter bind_params? The client object is instated with this line of code "client = DataFrameClient(host, port, user, password, dbname)"

Comment: @resolver101 can you run `help(client.query)` in interactive mode to ensure we are talking about the same method